# How do I set the background colour/image to be stacked above another expanded widget? Or is there another way

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Currently the only way I could make this kind of curved effect would be through making 2 container, making 1 a child of another and making 1 container's colour into the background colour.
However I cannot replicate this effect if the background is an image. Could anyone assist?

[image]

Example of the code I use:

```
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 100,
        color: Color(0xFF0D6068),
      ),
      Expanded(
          child: Container(
        color: Color(0xFF0D6068),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                topRight: Radius.circular(50),
              )),
        ),
      ))
    ],
  )),
);
```

Comment: use `ClipPath` widget

Comment: or even better for your case `ClipRRect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a Stack widget to achieve this, such that the background color or image would be at the back then the curved container would be stacked on it. Here is an example code.

```
Stack(children <Widget> [
        Image.asset(''),
        Container()
   ]
)
```

Instead of using an image asset, you can make use of BoxDecoration with the decoration parameter of a container. The BoxDecoration has an image parameter where you can provide your image with a DecorationImage() widget.